# How can I change the width of a select bar based on the amount of text in the option without hardcoding?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-select

How can I change the width of a select bar based on the amount of text in the option without hardcoding?

```
<select name = "jobs" class = "jo">
    <option value = "All" selected>All</option>
    <option value = "Fi">Architecture and Engineering</option>
    <option value = "Fi">Arts Design, Entertainment, and Sports</option> 
    <option value = "Fi">Engineering</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Always keeps it's width auto

```
select.jo {
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: how can I make the select button smaller when the option is <all> for instance without hardcoding.

Comment: @BenjaminSloutsky Why would you ever _want_ to do that? It makes it so much harder for a user to use, as its size would keep jumping around as they selected options. If there really is a use case for this in your app, chances are you want some custom element instead - there definitely isn't a way to to do this natively in CSS, I imagine you could do it with JS (e.g. `getBoundingClientRect` comes to mind) but it would be far easier to just make your own one / use a library that adds one, especially as I imagine you're probably trying to do other custom styling for it too.